# Is it possible to use thread protocol stack with sub 1 Ghz IEEE 802.15.4-2006 compliant radio?

Tags: openthread

I'm looking to port Open Thread to Beagle Bone and planning on using a sub 1Ghz radio, AT86RF212B. Is it possible to use the open thread protocol stack with this transceiver?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using other PHYs has been discussed on the forums ([subgig](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/openthread-users/sub%7Csort:date/openthread-users/-Pmq0cbp4jg/IZrDvGmhGwAJ), [UWB](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/openthread-users/_5bTX7rUxyw/discussion).)

tl;dr it is possible, but no implemented, and not defined in the current Thread specification.